# Is there a way to read and convert a language config file into an object?

Tags: c#, wpf, config

I wanted to add language support into my new project. I thought of creating a config file, similar to json.

So this is an example file:

```
{
  "LabelTextMainMenu": "This is the main Label",
  "LabelTextName": "Please enter your name"
}
```

Now what I want to reach is this (Classname not existing):

```
LangConfig config = File.ReadAllText(path/to/language/config);

public string LabelName
{
  get {config.LabelTextName}
}
```

Before I'd write this "LangConfig"-Class myself, i'd like to know if there's something that works in the way I want it?

Comment: you can use `Resources` like [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299436/WPF-Localization-for-Dummies) demonstrates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize the config file to typed object via Json.Net (or equivalent package).
Below is the sample implementation :

```
var configData = File.ReadAllText(path/to/language/config.config);
LangConfig config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LangConfig>(configData);
```

with the typed object, the properties can be accessed as

```
public string LabelName
{
  get {config.LabelTextName}
}
```